# Server error 500 when accessing Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-5.8

After installing laravel in **blog** directory, when I try to check it runs normally or not by accessing **localhost/blog/public** it shows **500 Server error** like this screenshot :

[image]

I've tried to grant apache with **mod_rewrite** and it didn't help.

I installed laravel with XAMPP in Windows.

======

UPDATE :
Here is the log file in the `storage/logs/` and **.env** file
[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19hBYAXlAnVgUQocwh8NDNS5aGwgk3hmV?usp=sharing)

Comment: Which PHP, Apache version do you have?

Comment: What command did you use to install Laravel in the blog directory?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei I'm using PHP 7.3.3 and Apache 2.4.38 which is in the newest version of xampp.

Comment: @mdexp I downloaded laravel manually from laravel/laravel GitHub, and then ran cmd command **composer install** in **blog** directory

Comment: Then make sure you have the .env file in the root of your project. If so try running: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Check if you can find anything under storage/logs inside the Laravel app. Probably a case of key not being generated yet. Do you have a .env file in the laravel directory?

Comment: @mdexp Yes I have the **.env** file and run the command you give, but it still gives the same error

Comment: @ZulfikarSandyPratama Can you please post your .env file?

Comment: Find apache error logs and check  it.

Comment: Please post the Apache error logs or Laravel logs (found in `storage/logs/laravel-*.log`

Comment: I've posted a link for .env and log file

Comment: try to debug using xdebug in your preferred ide, my error was one of the variable has not set in the response and i was aborting. using abort(500);

Answer (score 33):

do you have .env file

in terminal

```
cp .env.example .env

php artisan key:generate

chmod 777 -R  storage
```

Comment: Yes I have the .env file. I've uploaded on the link above. I'm using windows and I've granted the `/storage` directory a full control, but it still shows Server error 500

Comment: what is your php version ? 5.x or 7.x

Comment: @Zulfikar can you share us your log file laravel under storage/logs

Comment: I just encountered this Error 500 and this is what solved it for me. I didn't even had to use the `chmod` line.

Answer (score 6):

you must execute these commands

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

if it doesn't work
your .env file replace with `APP_KEY=base64:jxfiwITVfhauwt6clRR2plSXNg+KHlDbgIUQYIXvkVI=`

Answer (score 3):

I face the same issue with Laravel `5.8` but it was online. The way to resolve was to create a `.env` file which was missing after I transferred it from localhost. Also transfer all it's content into the new `.env` file.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem.
My solution is

1. create .env file from .evn.example
2. generate key by using this command
   php artisan key:generate

Answer (score 1):

In my case .env file was added in .gitignore so that's why when I cloned my Git repository on server I didn't get it there so that was the root cause why I was getting 500 error on server without any clue or error log.
So the issue was fixed by uploading .env file on server -OR- removing .env entry in .gitignore file the committing it in Git repository before taking Git pull on server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following things
1. Composer update /install 
2. Check storage folder has correct permission

And other steps mentioned in above reply.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the file name  .env.example to .env  which could found in the root directory . Then check in that file APP_debug =true . If that's okk then open cmd and 
php artisan key:generate

Then again start the server .

Answer (score 0):

You must try this:

```
php artisan key:generate **strong text**
```

and give the 777 permission for this `project.**strong text**`
then `run php artisan serve` command.

Answer (score 0):

If u give full access to Your Root Folder.Check Once. Then Give Full Access to All sub-folders In your application.

Open this Link - https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Copy the Below Files -

```
.editorconfig
.env.example
.gitattributes
.gitattributes
.gitattributes
```

And Paste it in You Application Root Folder. Now Run The file. Its working fine For me. If u have any pblm in php version or config laravel can't install the above files. SO u need to download it and Paste it in your Root folder.

If your pblm is Still not solved. Dont get tired. Just download the laravel files from git, it surely works.